# Woocommerce 3.0 related products - only show in stock related products

Tags: filter, woocommerce, related-posts

I'm trying to filter the products shown in "related products" in woocommerce so that it only outputs related products that are in stock.
but i cant find filters for woocommerce 3.0

Comment: It's here in [`woocommerce_product_related_posts_query`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/0b60af0774d998ce949c7eb71257b2a91bc7c370/includes/data-stores/class-wc-product-data-store-cpt.php#L981)